# Wait on HANDLE while processing messages for a specific HWND

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, window

I have a wait handle ([`CreateEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396.aspx)) and a window handle ([`CreateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632679.aspx)). On the UI thread, I want to process messages *for that HWND only* until the wait handle is signaled.

[`GetMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx) will let me receive messages for a single window handle, but it doesn't know anything about wait handles.

[`MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684245.aspx) will let me wait for either the wait handle or a window message, but a message sent to any window on the current thread will unblock it -- there's no way to filter by HWND.

I can't just string those two together. If a message for a window unblocks the `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` call and I use `GetMessage` for a different HWND, the message remains in the queue, and the next `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` call returns immediately due to the unprocessed message. Loop ad infinitum.

Comment: And yes, I understand that I could post a message from the background thread to the window instead of using a wait handle, but... you know... implementation details. :)

Comment: Don't pass the `MWMO_INPUTAVAILABLE` flag to `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`. Then it will wake up only if a new message arrives; it will ignore pre-existing messages.

Comment: If you stop processing messages for certain windows then they're liable to appear nonresponsive to the user - is that really what you want?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Yes. This is a critical shutdown-time thread synchronization.

Comment: Aha. RTFM, I guess. :) "MWMO_INPUTAVAILABLE -- The function returns if input exists for the queue, even if the input has been seen (but not removed) using a call to another function, such as PeekMessage."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DWORD dwRet;
do
{
    dwRet = MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(1, &hEvent, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT, 0);
    if (dwRet == (WAIT_OBJECT_0+1))
    {
        while (PeekMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    // ...
}
while (dwRet != WAIT_OBJECT_0);
```

Comment: The call to `PeekMessage` should be: `PeekMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)`.

Comment: Thanks, Remy. I'd like to give the answer to @RaymondChen, though. He was the first to suggest not using the MWMO_INPUTAVAILABLE flag.